# How can I display a map with traffic information in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, dictionary, traffic

How can I display a map with traffic information in my native iOS app?

I know that there is MKMapView and the MapKit framework. But there is no mention on how to use display the live traffic information of Google.

I don't need much interaction - just to show the map within a particular region along with the traffic data.

Any hints to a possible implementation appreciated (including native and web-based solutions, any map service, with decent content for Europe/Germany preferred).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't show the traffic information using the MK framework. You will probably have to use a UIWebView to do this.